# I am trying to import a set of lists in python and call a random item from one of the lists

Tags: python, list, import

```
#Set of lists I want to import into my python program called "setlist.txt"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tripolee = ('Saeed Younan', 'Matrixxman', 'Pete Tong', 'Dubfire', 'John Digweed', 'Carl Cox')
Ranch = ('Dabin', 'Galantis', 'Borgeous', 'Shpongle', 'ODESZA', 'Kaskade')
Sherwood = ('Nadus', 'Mr. Carmack', 'Wave Racer', 'Lido', 'Goldlink', 'Four Tet', 'Flume')
Jubilee = ('Chaz French', 'MartyParty', 'Sango', 'Brodinski', 'Phutureprimitive', 'EOTO')
The Hangar = ('Vourteque', 'The Gentlemen Callers', 'Bart&Baker', 'Jaga Jazzist', 'JPOD')
Forest = ('Vibe Street', 'Lafa Taylor', 'Vaski', 'Little People', 'jackLNDN', 'MartyParty')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#program

from sys import exit
from random import randint
from sys import argv

script, setlist = argv

setlist = open(setlist)

print "Here is the setlist for day 1"
print setlist.read()
print "%r is playing on the Tripolee stage" % random.choice(setlist.readline(2))
```

I have a bunch more code in between all this that I"m not putting up here but basically that last line what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: You have a text file full of assignments?

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: It only ouputs ' ' instead of one of the items on the list

Comment: @VincentBrown, none of your code is going to work, you have already exhausted the iterator using read so there is nothing to read using readline, not even the 2 bytes you are trying to read. You have a txt file not lists.

Comment: Alright, so how do I display the contents of setlist without having read exhaust() the iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best format for your file but you can split and use ast.literal_eval:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("in.txt") as f:
    choices = [literal_eval(line.split(" = ")[-1]) for line in f]
```

Which will give you a list of tuples which you can pass to random.choice:

```
[('Saeed Younan', 'Matrixxman', 'Pete Tong', 'Dubfire', 'John Digweed', 'Carl Cox'), ('Dabin', 'Galantis', 'Borgeous', 'Shpongle', 'ODESZA', 'Kaskade'), ('Nadus', 'Mr. Carmack', 'Wave Racer', 'Lido', 'Goldlink', 'Four Tet', 'Flume'), ('Chaz French', 'MartyParty', 'Sango', 'Brodinski', 'Phutureprimitive', 'EOTO'), ('Vourteque', 'The Gentlemen Callers', 'Bart&Baker', 'Jaga Jazzist', 'JPOD'), ('Vibe Street', 'Lafa Taylor', 'Vaski', 'Little People', 'jackLNDN', 'MartyParty')]
```

I have no idea where setlist is supposed to come from, you file is what looks like tuple assignments. `setlist.readline(2)` would read 2 bytes or actually in your case nothing as you have already exhausted the file iterator calling `read`.

I would suggest after extracting using literal_eval putting your file in a more usable format, maybe creating a dict using the name as the key and dumping the dict.

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("in.txt") as f:
    choices = {}
    for line in f:
        ven, tpl = line.split(" = ")
        choices[ven] = literal_eval(tpl)
    print(choices)
```

Output:

```
{'Jubilee': ('Chaz French', 'MartyParty', 'Sango', 'Brodinski', 'Phutureprimitive', 'EOTO'), 'Tripolee': ('Saeed Younan', 'Matrixxman', 'Pete Tong', 'Dubfire', 'John Digweed', 'Carl Cox'), 'The Hangar': ('Vourteque', 'The Gentlemen Callers', 'Bart&Baker', 'Jaga Jazzist', 'JPOD'), 'Ranch': ('Dabin', 'Galantis', 'Borgeous', 'Shpongle', 'ODESZA', 'Kaskade'), 'Sherwood': ('Nadus', 'Mr. Carmack', 'Wave Racer', 'Lido', 'Goldlink', 'Four Tet', 'Flume'), 'Forest': ('Vibe Street', 'Lafa Taylor', 'Vaski', 'Little People', 'jackLNDN', 'MartyParty')}
```

You can persist the dict using `json.dump` or the `pickle` module so your data will be in a lot easier format to each time.

To make it a little clearer what you have below is the content of your .txt file:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tripolee = ('Saeed Younan', 'Matrixxman', 'Pete Tong', 'Dubfire', 'John Digweed', 'Carl Cox')
Ranch = ('Dabin', 'Galantis', 'Borgeous', 'Shpongle', 'ODESZA', 'Kaskade')
Sherwood = ('Nadus', 'Mr. Carmack', 'Wave Racer', 'Lido', 'Goldlink', 'Four Tet', 'Flume')
Jubilee = ('Chaz French', 'MartyParty', 'Sango', 'Brodinski', 'Phutureprimitive', 'EOTO')
The Hangar = ('Vourteque', 'The Gentlemen Callers', 'Bart&Baker', 'Jaga Jazzist', 'JPOD')
Forest = ('Vibe Street', 'Lafa Taylor', 'Vaski', 'Little People', 'jackLNDN', 'MartyParty')
```

To print the venue and set list you can use dict.items:

```
for ven, set_l in choices.items():
    print("Set list for {}: {}".format(ven, ", ".join(set_l)))
```

Output:

```
Set list for Jubilee:  Chaz French, MartyParty, Sango, Brodinski, Phutureprimitive, EOTO
Set list for Tripolee:  Saeed Younan, Matrixxman, Pete Tong, Dubfire, John Digweed, Carl Cox
Set list for The Hangar:  Vourteque, The Gentlemen Callers, Bart&Baker, Jaga Jazzist, JPOD
Set list for Ranch:  Dabin, Galantis, Borgeous, Shpongle, ODESZA, Kaskade
Set list for Sherwood:  Nadus, Mr. Carmack, Wave Racer, Lido, Goldlink, Four Tet, Flume
Set list for Forest:  Vibe Street, Lafa Taylor, Vaski, Little People, jackLNDN, MartyParty
```

When you open the file and call `read` you now have all the content in your file stored as a string. You then print the string, next you try `random.choice(setlist.readline(2))`, `readline(2)` is trying to read two bytes which it cannot even do as the file pointer is at the end of the file as you have already called `read` so you see an empty string outputted.

If you want to get a random string from the first tuple:

```
choices = [literal_eval(line.split(" = ")[-1]) for line in f]
from random import choice
print(choice(choices[0]))
```

Comment: Setlist is just supposed to be a file with a set of lists I want to call items from.  I guess my question then becomes how do I pick one of the names off the first list?

Comment: @VincentBrown, a file has strings inside not lists and in your case if they are evaluated you have tuples.

Comment: I'm still new to the terminology...I have a file called "setlist". Inside this file I have multiple lists each with strings inside them.  I want to call one of the strings at random out from one of the lists that I chose (so not random) from the file setlist.  How can I do that?

Comment: You have no lists inside anything. You have strings which resemble assigning names to tuples. I have added the code of how to get all the tuple like strings from the file and as actual tuples, any of which you can pass to random.choice

Comment: @VincentBrown, I added a way to store the data in a dict, you can access each tuple by key `choice['Jubilee']` etc..